# R encoding UTF-8: U+0080-U+009F

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding

I am struggling with some encoding issues. I have many textfiles that contain rows in the following format:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94114397/example.txt

According to Notepad++, these are all encoded in UTF-8 and most non-ASCII characters are displayed correctly, as you can see in lines 1 and 2. However, I have problems with some characters that seem to be wrongly interpreted(?). In my example file, this the case in line 3 in the word "Lakuic", where there should be an "š" between the "u" and the "i". There actually is a character between those two letters which can be seen by copy-pasting the word into the google chrome address bar.

Now when I read the data in R, it displays "Laku< U+009A>ic". How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try adding encoding to the read eg. read.table("saveFile", header=F, sep="\t", quote="\"",encoding="latin1")

Comment: I already tried that with different encodings ("latin1", "Windows1253",...), always resulting in wrongly displayed special characters all over the document.

Comment: I think this is Windows-1252.  Copy Lakuic into a blank R file, save as UTF encoding.  Open the file - not correct.  Choose File - ReOpen with Encoding and choose Windows-1252.  Is correct for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting from UTF-8 to latin1:

```
    df <- read.table("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94114397/example.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding="UTF-8")
    iconv(df[, 1], from = "UTF-8", to = "latin1")
    # [1] "Trichocentrum<->longifolium<-><->(Lindl.) R.Jiménez, Acta Bot. Mex. 97: 54 (2011)." 
    # [2] "Salvia<->× hegelmaieri<->nothosubsp. accidentalis<->(Sánchez-Gómez & R.Morales)."   
    # [3] "Edraianthus<->tarae<-><->Lakušic, Bilten Drustva Ekologa BiH, Ser. A 4: 108 (1987)."
```

My `sessioInfo()`:

```
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
# 
# locale:
#   [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252
```

Comment: That actually seems to work. Can you explain why reading as latin1 doesn't work but reconverting from UTF-8 to latin1 does?

Comment: No, unfortunately not - encoding issues have always been a mistery to me => trial & error.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
file1   <- "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94114397/example.txt"
result <- read.table(file1, header=F, sep="\t", quote="\"",encoding="windows-1252")
```

Comment: No, it doesn't do the trick on my machine. All other special characters are corrupted, e.g.: "R.Jiménez" --> "R.JimÃ©nez" or even "Lakuic" --> "LakuÂšic"