# Encoding Issue when fetching data from MySQL DB into R

Tags: mysql, r, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I'm using the "RMySQL" library in R to load data from a local MySQL DB into R:

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="root", password="****", dbname="twitterdata", host="localhost")
dataframe <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT id, plaintext, category FROM table")
```

When I inspect the dataframe, I see a lot of unformatted characters such as the slanted apastrophe (**´**) which shows up as **â€™**.

After some research, I discovered that according to [this](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html) site, some special characters (including the slanted apastrophe) are not part of the **ISO-8859-1** standard but of the **Windows-1252** standard.

When I run

```
Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")
```

in R, it says:

```
"German_Austria.1252"
```

Doesn't it already say that I'm on the correct encoding?!
In my DB (Default Charset: UTF-8), the apostrophe is encoded well.

I also tried to add a parameter to the dbConnect statement **DBMSencoding="utf-8"** but with no effect.

When I run

```
Encoding(x)
```

in R (where x is the character vector - a sentence), the answer is

```
"unknown"
```

Does anybody know now to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595862/r-encoding-utf-8-u0080-u009f/30596689#30596689) help? Afaik, a `'` should be part of iso-8859-x as well as utf-8. You probably need to encode it correctly within R.

Comment: Yes the ' is part of the iso-8859-x, but not the ´ and the `. The interesing thing is that when I write the data to a file, it's correctly shown again.

Comment: So, did you try `iconv(dataframe [, 1], from = "UTF-8", to = "latin1")` as suggested? It's hard to debug without having access to the actual data...

Comment: Oh man! That works! I don't know how I could overlooked that! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Okay, doesn't work either. When I do that, some entries simply become "NA"...

Comment: `NA` the default for the `sub` parameter of `iconv`. See `?iconv`: _"If not NA it is used to replace any non-convertible bytes in the input. (This would normally be a single character, but can be more.) If "byte", the indication is "<xx>" with the hex code of the byte."_. However, as I said, without having the data, it's an endless guessing game. You should add an excerpt to your post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1):

Do it:

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="root", password="****", dbname="twitterdata", host="localhost", encoding = "latin1")
```